# Backbone error, Object add has no method 'bind'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

```
items.bind 'add', (item) => 
    @addOne(item)

addOne: (item) ->
    view = new ListItem({model: item})
```

..initialization of the view throws this error: TypeError: Object add has no method 'bind'

```
class ListItem extends Backbone.View

    el: $ '#wrap'

    template: $ '#listItem'

    initialize: () ->
        @model.bind 'change', @render, @ 
        @model.bind 'destroy', @remove, @

    render: () ->
        @el.append @template.tmpl @model.toJSON()
```

EDIT: logging item before setting the view results in...

```
Item
_callbacks: Object
_changed: false
_changing: false
_escapedAttributes: Object
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
cid: "c2"
collection: Items
__proto__: ctor
```

but if I log @model when initializing the view it's an empty object called add

EDIT 2: item.bind is undefined from within addOne, not sure why though

Comment: I'm unable to replicate. Are you using the latest version of Backbone.js?

Comment: @Trevor Backbone.js 0.5.0, Ill update it and see if anything changes?

Comment: Might be worth trying with 0.5.3? Also, you've checked that `item.bind` is a function from within `addOne`, right?

Comment: @Trevor ahh, item.bind is undefined, i'm not sure what this means though. (updated to 5.3 too)

Comment: @Trevor, I'm not sure what solved it because I just kinda re built the section I thought was causing the issue. My guess is that I was accidentally passing a reference to this somewhere odd. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, but the object that you've added to `items` doesn't appear to be a valid model. What code are you using for your `items.add` call? Verify that you don't get an error when you run `items.add(new Backbone.Model)`.

Perhaps you did

```
items.add [{foo: bar}]
```

but set the `model` property on the `Collection` class that `items` is an instance of to something other than a `Backbone.Model` subclass?